# How to conditionally disable enter key on keypress

Tags: jquery

disabled the enter key using keypress in jquery

```
$('.ui-dialog').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.charCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)
        return false;
});
```

Under specific conditions, the enter key should be enabled again.

How can I enable it again? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Unbind the keypress function:

```
$(".ui-dialog").unbind("keypress");
```

Comment: Hi, I used your answer and it's perfect, the other answer is correct too! Why didn't I thought of this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a flag into your event handler to enable/disable the behavior:

```
$('.ui-dialog').keypress(function(e){
    if ( feature_enabled ){
      if (e.charCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)
          return false;
    }
});
```

Then in another part of your application all you need to do is toggle the `feature_enabled` flag.

If you want to scrap that behavior altogether then you can simply unbind the event handler using jQuery's [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) functions.

Comment: The week is almost over... We get tired...Programmers are people too ;) Happens to the best of us.